# Limit of Step Functions

Tags: measure-theory

It is well known that a measurable function (on a set of finite measure) is limit **almost everywhere** of a sequence of step functions. I would like to see an example of a measurable function which can not be limit **everywhere** of any sequence of step function. (Here limits are understood as point-wise limits).

I thought the example of Dirichlet function on $[0,1]$ would work; but I am not sure.

Comment: Dirichlet's function is exactly the example.

Comment: What is your definition of a step function? Do you mean a step function in the sense of Riemann?

Comment: $f$ is step function on $\mathbb{R}$ means there are finite disjoint intervals $[a_k,b_k]$, $k=1,2,\cdots,n$, such that $f$ is constant on $(a_k,b_k)$, it can take any finite value at $a_k$'s and $b_k$'s, and $f$ is zero outside these intervals.